# how to add bootstrap progress bar to angular countdown timer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add **bootstrap progress bar** to angular countdown timer.
Here is my app.js

```
function AlbumCtrl($scope,$timeout) {
    $scope.counter = 100;
    $scope.onTimeout = function(){
        $scope.counter--;
        mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);
    }
    var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);

    $scope.stop = function(){
        $timeout.cancel(mytimeout);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is your problem?

Comment: The problem is pretty clear in the title but @chetan perhaps you can explain what you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what version of bootstrap you use.

**Angular UI Bootstrap**

```
<div ng-controller="AlbumCtrl">
    <progressbar value="counter"></progressbar>
</div>
```

**Boortstrap 3**

```
<div ng-controller="AlbumCtrl">    
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{counter}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ng-style="{width:counter+'%'}">
            <span class="sr-only">{{counter}}% Complete</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when I set $scope.counter = 600; progress bar doesn't work. any help as i want to increase my counter beyond 100

Comment: You need to define a range. if you're using angular-ui you can set it with a max attribute `max=600` for example the regular bootstrap has `aria-valuemax="600"`

Comment: i did this in first attempt iteself but it's not working

Comment: You are missing this in your plunkr: `ng-style="{width:counter/600*100+'%'}"`

Comment: thank you so much, i appreciate your help. it's working:)

Comment: No problem. would really appreciate it if you mark my answer as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

you could use bootstrap ui built-in directive:  https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/progressbar

here is a plunkr based on your code: http://plnkr.co/edit/jC1GLH6Nfo6oQqq5um40?p=preview

html:

```
<div ng-controller="ProgressCtrl">
    <h3>Static</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"><progressbar value="counter"></progressbar></div>
    </div>
</div>
```